# Spring web application set datasource based on customer/user

Tags: java, spring

I have a Spring web application that uses multiple databases. There are multiple customers and each customer has his own database. One master database (customer auth DB) has customer information and connections strings(or metadata) to the customer databases stored. I have created 2 datasource bean definitions in Spring configuration files. So, I would like to set the second datasource based on customer.
                               I have tried setting the 2nd datasource based on customer.
The problem is see is that when another customer logs in, the 2nd datasource switches to the new customers database. I think my approach is completely wrong. Any ideas?? or can we set some kind of scope to avoid the problem. My Spring config files have the following definitions:

```
    <bean id="customerDS" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" lazy-init="true">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="${property.cust.db.driver}" />        
      <property name="url" value="${property.cust.db.url}" />
      <property name="username" value="${property.cust.db.username}" />
      <property name="password" value="${property.cust.db.password}" />      
    </bean>

    <bean id="userAuthDS" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="${property.userauth.db.driver}" />        
      <property name="url" value="${property.userauth.db.url}" />
      <property name="username" value="${property.userauth.db.username}" />
      <property name="password" value="${property.userauth.db.password}" />
    </bean>
```

I have the following code to set the second datasource based on customer who logs in:

```
@Autowired
private DriverManagerDataSource customerDS;
if(customer.equals("cust1")){
customerDS.setUrl("jdbc:sybase:Tds:127.0.0.1:2679?ServiceName=cust1");
customerDS.setUsername("dba");
customerDS.setPassword("sql");
}
if(customer.equals("cust2")){
customerDS.setUrl("jdbc:sybase:Tds:127.0.0.1:2689?ServiceName=cust1");
customerDS.setUsername("dba");
customerDS.setPassword("sql");
}
```

Comment: Can we see what your actually doing? Perhaps the Bean configuration files, as well as the code that switches the databases...

Comment: I have edited the question to include some code. I see that I am doing it wrong. Lets say customer 1 logs in, the customerDS is set to database "cust1". AT the same time if customer 2 logs in, the customerDS is set to database "cust2". So, now both customer 1 and customer 2 are using "cust2" database

Comment: You will need a new Datasource object for each customer and look them up with every request.

Comment: @Bart I dont know how to look up datasource for each customer and at what layer of application to include it (Data Access?). Can you provide an example code or link?

Comment: Yes I can provide an example. `Datasource ds = MyServiceBean.findDataSourceByCustomerName("cust1");`

Answer (score 0):

The following link helped me with the problem:
http://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/

If you carefully read and understand the spring configuration, you should be able to achieve it.